# How much can I make (or how many hours can I work) while receiving social security benefits?

Tags: united-states, benefits

I currently am on medication and was recently approved for SSI benefits including cash assistance and food stamps. The money comes in monthly with no problem but I can't afford housing with just this and need a second form of income. I was wondering if anyone knew how much, or if there is any place online, where I can find out how many hours i can work/how much money I can make without cutting into my benefits.

Comment: The answer depends on several undisclosed factors including your age.  Have you tried looking at the [Social Security web site](http://www.ssa.gov) to find the answers, or tried just _asking_ the Social Security Administration?

Comment: ... and your location. Please at least add a country tag.

Comment: Do other countries use "Social Security" or that US-only?

Answer (score 4):

As Dilip commented, the Social Security web site is pretty comprehensive.

[Understanding Supplemental Security Income SSI Income](http://www.socialsecurity.gov/ssi/text-income-ussi.htm) has the details you are looking for.

It's a convoluted equation. You lose SSI at a pretty fast rate as earned income rises. The system is not kind to those who qualify for SSI but try to earn some money to cover their needs.

Comment: Dilip mentioned age--how does that factor in?  I don't see it in your link but may be missing it.

Comment: Dilip would have to address this. I was happy enough to get to a nice relevant document.